# Output contents of for loop into array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

```
for ($numbers1 = 1; $numbers1 <= 150; ++$numbers1)
  {
       echo "the number " . $numbers1;
       echo "<br>";
  }
```

I have the practice for loop above. I need to return the data into an array and loop through and print the data to the page. I would GREATLY appreciate if you could break apart your answer with notations explaining this as I am trying to learn. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*
 * Initilalize variable with an empty array.
 * Array can contain variables of any type, even other arrays and grows in size automatically.
 * In PHP 5.4 and newer you can use `$data = [];` syntax
 */
$data = array();

/*
 * Set variable $numbers1 to 1, then check that its value less than or equal to 150 and then run code between { and }
 * After the very last line in the `{ }` block perform variable increment (++$numbers1) - add 1 to the previous value.
 * Now $numbers1 becomes equal to 2, then check that its value less than or equal to 150 and again.
 * Loop will iterate over and over untill $numbers1 become eqial to 151 and `$numbers1 <= 150` evaluates to false.
 * Then loop breaks and code after closind `}` will be executed.
 */
for ($numbers1 = 1; $numbers1 <= 150; ++$numbers1)
{
    /*
     * Set variable $value to the string. String will be built from 3 parts 
     *  - "the number ", 
     *  - string representation of $numbers1 value and
     *  - literal string "<br/>\n"
     *
     * "\n" means 'new line' symbol, in HTML is transforms into the space, but it will help you to debug your application -
     * you can see resulting code more structured in "view-source" mode of your browser (Ctrl+U in Firefox).
     * You can safely remove it.
     */
    $value = "the number " . $numbers1 . "<br/>\n";

    /**
     * Then add $value to the array. It is equivalent to array_push($data, $value)
     * String 'the number 1<br/>' becomes the first element (at 0 index, try to `echo $data[0];` somewhere),
     * string 'the number 2<br/>' becomes the second one ($data[1]) and so on.
     */
    $data[] = $value;
}

/* Tt is good habit to unset variables that you don not need anymore.
 * Try to `echo $value` and you will got Notice - variable does not exist.
 */
unset ($value, $numbers1);

/*
 * For page output you should use some kind of templating engine (Twig, for example). For now, we will use PHP itself
 */

// After this line starts plain HTML, PHP engine will output is as is. Like web server usially does.
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <?php 
                /*
                 * Meet PHP code again.
                 * All that printed or echoed will be put in place of the code between open and closing php tags
                 */
                foreach ($data as $value) {
                    echo $value;
                }
            ?>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, you must teach for a living. I am going to save this as reference material. 1 question though, If i insert a Print_r before the echo statement, will it show both the print_r and the echo, or will the print_r clear the array when it outputs?

Comment: what would you call this? You didn't use an "array_push" like i expected.

Comment: @DanMan3395, `print_r echo $array;` will produce parse error. `echo`, `print` and `print_r` do no modifications in their arguments. `$array[] = 'val` [acts](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) a little bit different that array_push does, but for this code example they are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

```
$numbers_array = array();

for ($numbers1 = 1; $numbers1 <= 150; ++$numbers1)
  {
       array_push($numbers_array,$numbers1);//add the number to the array
  }

print_r($numbers_array);//print out the array
```

If you want to only print the values, you can add this line to the for loop:

```
var_dump($numbers_array[$numbers1-1]);//prints out the element in the position that is one less then the number you want to print out (since arrays in php are zero based)
```

Comment: So if i am reading this correctly, the for statement actually acts kind of like a function in that it runs whats in the brackets after even check of the statement? 

That is to say, you literally just replaced my echo of the number with an array function, named it "$numbers_array, then occupid it with $numbers1. so each round of the loop, the array gets another result added until the loops stops?